# Using requirejs 2.1.5 and the google cdn

Tags: jquery, requirejs, google-cdn

I am just beginning to use the requirejs api, but have an initial question concerning using the google CDN.

Currently, to get the latest jquery and jqueryui I am using the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=myKey"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
//=== Load in any web modules necessary
    google.load("jquery", "1");
    google.load("jqueryui", "1");
</script>
```

Is it possible to use this structure, or something similar, with requirejs? If so, what would the main.js file look like?

Also, can the requirejs also control the css inclusions?

Answer (score 0):

radi8, as far as I know (& I might be mistaken) RequireJS is only useful for handling JS dependencies.  In CSS you can use @import, but you need to provide a hard-coded URL.  If you want more robust CSS handling I'd suggest investigating Less or Sass.

UPDATE:  Actually, I've been reading up on & playing with RequireJS and found this tasty tidbit, from the [API usage page](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#usage):

```
define(["require"], function(require) {
   var cssUrl = require.toUrl("./style.css");
});
```

Obviously it pays to fiddle about with this, see if it suits your use-case, etc.  Hope this helps.